# Calculating the total possible combinations of given variables with weights

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have a set of 5 types of toys - T1, T2, T3, T4, T5. I invite a kid to select toys of his/her choice with the following conditions:

1. The kid must choose exactly 3 toys.
2. The maximum units that can be selected of any type is 3.
3. There is no restriction on what toy is selected as long as the above conditions are satisfied. i.e., duplicates of a same type are allowed.

I would like to calculate the total number of combinations that are possible for the kid to choose his/her favorite toys. For this, I need to consider all the possible scenarios:

1. All 3 toys are of the same type.
2. 2 of one type of toy and 1 of another type.
3. All 3 toys are of different types.

Supposing the kid chooses to go with the same type of toy, then it is easy to say that the possible combinations are $C_1^5$.

The following is the part that I'm a little unsure about:

1. If the kid chooses to go with 2 of a certain type and 1 of another type, am I right in deducing that the total possible combinations of that approach is $C_2^5 + C_1^5$?
2. If the kid chooses to go with 3 different types of toys, is the total possible combinations $C_3^5$?

Comment: It does not say anywhere that the kid must choose _exactly_ $3$ toys.

Comment: @MathLover Sorry about that. Just updated the conditions to reflect the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have the right cases -

$(i)$ All three toys of one type
$(ii)$ Two toys of one type and third of another
$(iii)$ All three toys of different types

Your count for $(ii)$ is not correct.

For $(i)$, it is $ \displaystyle {5 \choose 1}$ as you said.

For $(ii)$, it is $ \displaystyle 2 \cdot {5 \choose 2} ~ $. You first choose two types of toys and then there are two ways to choose the type we would have two toys of. Say we selected type $T_1$ and $T_3$. We can have two of $T_1$ and one of $T_3$ OR two of $T_3$ and one of $T_1$.

For $(iii)$, it is $ \displaystyle {5 \choose 3}$ as you said.

Adding, you get $35$ ways of selecting toys with the given conditions.

---

However an easier method exists using stars and bars. You will have to make yourself familiar with it first though.

There are $5$ types of toys and we choose $0, 1, 2$ or $3$ of each type such that the total number of selected toys are $3$. This is equivalent to the number of solutions to,

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 3$ where $x_i$ is non-negative integer.

Using stars and bars method, number of solutions is,

$ \displaystyle {{3 + 5 - 1} \choose {5 - 1}} = 35$

Comment: Okay. Great. Got it. Supposing the kid can choose 4 toys (max. of a kind as well as total), then the equation becomes 5C1 + (2 * 5C2) + (2 * 5C3) + 5C4. Correct?

Comment: Do you know stars and bars method? If yes, I can update the above answer to show an easier way.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of stars and bars. I can read about it though.

Comment: I just updated with stars and bars. Also if you are counting by cases, for the $4$ toys, answer should be ${5 \choose 1} + 3 * {5 \choose 2} + 3 * {5 \choose 3} + {5 \choose 4}$. Sorry for typo earlier.

Comment: stars and bars method - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: Got it. Learnt about a new method today as well. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

1. this scenario is 51*41 = 20
   the reason for 51 is because you choose the type not the amount
   their left one type and 4 choices so 41
   when you do things in different steps you multiply them
   so the answer should be the product
2. your second think is correct the answer is 53 = 10

Answer (score 0):

We can biject this problem into another problem. Instead of having a kid pick 3 toys, let's consider the 3 choices as 3 indistinguishable coins (since you didn't directly state so, I'm assuming the order of choice does not matter (if the order did matter, the answer would simply be $5^3$)). We will consider the toys being chosen as 5 distinguishable bins.

This problem is equivalent to the number of ways to distribute the 3 coins to the 5 bins. Using urns-and-balls (or whatever equivalent name you know), the number of ways to do so is $\binom{5+3-1}{3}=\boxed{35}$